# Generic Function and index access

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I've encountered a problem regarding typescript and need some help

I'm new to typescript and a code block below illustrates shortened version of my problem.

[Link to Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILOQbwFAYwNzgBsBXCARgC5kBnMKUAcwG5c9DSIAmauhkFmwwwSIBAAo4vekwA0yAEbT%20jAJTV8Ae2AATVgF9s2UJFiIUAISxDkHMlWQgSAWwXRWeW8TI9HLt1AeeCJiktROrtDySn6RUOq22nrI2IZGIQhgwJogyADyJKbIADwAKsgQAB6QIDo0aMgAPsgWAHzizgCeAGKiCNSlANoA5BnDALryUshDw3YUE9EDI-NcE6oYOJ5dvaFw0aoG2EA)

```
interface A  {
    value1: string;
    value2: string;
    func(a: string, b: string): void;
}

interface B {
    value1: number;
    value2: number;
    func(a: number, b: number): void; 
}


function Outer <T extends A | B>(myFunc: T['func'], a: T['value1'], b: T['value2'])  {
    myFunc(a, b); // get an error: Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
}
```

What I want is to pass parameters to 'Outer' function which will then infer 'T'.

I thought it would be okay to call 'myFunc', but error comes up and says I can't assign 'a' and 'b' to 'never'.

** This set of codes might look a bit weird.
It's actually intended to be a react hook.

What's going on here? and What would be a proper way to solve this?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of **union to intersection** behavior of typescript. Normally when the function `Outer` is called, it is not clear, what object type(`A` or `B`) is passed to it, so typescript considers the parameters of the `func` function in the form of the intersected types.

```
// it is not obvious that myFunc is this ? :
func(a: string, b: string): void;


//or this? :
func(a: number, b: number): void;


// so typescript changes it like this :
func(a:number & string, b: number & string) = func(a:never, b:never)

//since number set and string set do not have any intersection, the types are never.
```

What you can do is to consider separate types for the properties of each interface so that their intersection is an existing type.

```
type AValue =  {a1:string; a2:string}

interface A {
    value: AValue;
    func(x:AValue): void; 
}

type BValue =  {b1:number; b2:number}

interface B {
    value: BValue;
    func(x:BValue): void; 
}


function Outer <T extends A | B>(myFunc: T['func'], a: AValue & BValue)  {
    myFunc(a);
}
```

You can read more about union to intersection in typescript [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type).
Although it might be better to change the `Outer` function declaration and solve the problem in a different way so that this **union to intersecton** thing does not happen.

Comment: but now OP what have to pass an object to `a` containing `a1`, `a2` *and* `b1`, `b2` which is probably not what he had in mind.

Comment: It can be something like this `{a1:"foo", a2:"bar", b1:0, b2:0}`. But you're right. Always two useless props, either (`a1` and `a2`) or (`b1` and `b2`) should be passed to the function. I wanted to explain the mechanism of the issue. As I said it might be better to change the declaration of `Outer` or interfaces and raise the issue in another way.

Comment: Thanks a lot for detailed explanation. You got me in right direction.

Answer (score 0):

This particular example can be solved in a more elegant way

[Typescritp playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDBmFcDsGMBcEsD2kAEB5csCmAnAPACoB8AFALYCeAYlNAFwokCGDBANCgEasCUKAvERQA3RPAAmHFinZdeKFAG9gChZRoxmHTjwDcwAL4gA9MZRYAHkzIAHADZYU0JnbsBnYBmz5I4Mp1xSLR0BIUUnZDdEBwA6O0QAcxIUAAMmAGpOfhQAEkUMzgMUlB4DDhQANg4ADj0QL1w8N1gceEgEoKY2EMElCMgo2Pik1KZ%20PKYDLnHFQuLS8oAiJiZFjkXOTcW64FMUAE1EcCcmVCxhR0QyeFgUWAALR1k3NuhHG5QAd3hXFHhbOwUP63UCIHB3R4iFzgLBuFCIUAoABMkHEKEgTDRD0cD3gODRwmhWF2ZgAkqhcXDnM1gX84UwUOImNhPJhcCRgnxeuFoJFolg4olkmkZkwYrBEAAZRDOBwAZRabSSpWmeU44qlMpcWAAIsysArWu0SKUiiUygpIFhPig9dgTRwrTa7VgSIskQAGACMAHYALTegNe7Y7YBAA)

```js
function Outer<T>(myFunc: (a: T, b: T) => void, a: T, b: T)  {
    myFunc(a, b);
}

// example calls
Outer<number>((a,b) => { console.log( `a+b= ${a+b}` )},  6, 8);

Outer<string>((a,b) => { console.log( `a=${a} b=${b}` )},  "aa", "bbb");

// You can eve omit the T, since it will imply it for the values of 2nd nad the third value
// In this cast it is a date
Outer((a,b) => { console.log( `a=${a.toLocaleString()} b=${b.toLocaleDateString()}}` )},  new Date(), new Date("2017-01-01"));
```